# Multiple ifelse statement and %in%

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr

I have a dataset consisting of 1500 rows and 3 rows. I want to create a new row, that gives a name based on the data from another row.

What I have:

```
Bbg_Parks %>%
mutate(City = ifelse(FID_BBG2012_Clip %in% 1:4455, 
              "Rotterdam", 
ifelse(FID_BBG2012_Clip %in% 4744:5655 & 10335,
              "The_Hague",
ifelse(FID_BBG2012_Clip %in% 5861:7015,
              "Utrecht",
ifelse(FID_BBG2012_Clip %in% 7110:10190, 
              "Amsterdam", "no")))))
```

What I want:

```
Bbg_Parks %>%
  mutate(City = ifelse(FID_BBG2012_Clip %in% 1:4455 & 5736 & 10220:10330,
                "Rotterdam", 
  ifelse(FID_BBG2012_Clip %in% 4744:5655 & 10335, 
                "The_Hague",
  ifelse(FID_BBG2012_Clip %in% 5861:7015 & 10381:10385,
                "Utrecht",
  ifelse(FID_BBG2012_Clip %in% 7110:10190 & 10447:10488, 
                "Amsterdam", "no")))))
```

However, the last code doesn't work, as it gives me the error:

Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `City`.
x unused arguments ("Rotterdam", ifelse(FID_BBG2012_Clip %in% 4744:5655, 10335, "The_Hague", ifelse(FID_BBG2012_Clip %in% 5861:7015, 10381:10385, "Utrecht", ifelse(FID_BBG2012_Clip %in% 7110:10190, 10447:10488, "Amsterdam", "no")))).
i Input `City` is `ifelse(...)`. Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

So, basically I want to include a few more data points from the columns FID_BBG2012_Clip into the newly created column "City". Could someone help a brother out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 mutate(City = ifelse(FID_BBG2012_Clip %in% c(1:4455, 5736, 10220:10330),
                       "Rotterdam", 
                       ifelse(FID_BBG2012_Clip %in% c(4744:5655, 10335), 
                              "The_Hague",
                              ifelse(FID_BBG2012_Clip %in% c(5861:7015, 10381:10385),
                                     "Utrecht",
                                     ifelse(FID_BBG2012_Clip %in% c(7110:10190, 10447:10488), 
                                            "Amsterdam", "no")))))
```